# Why is my Codeigniter 4 query build 'select' returning all fields?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm new to Codeigniter 4 but very familiar with Codeigniter 3. I'm trying to write a simple DB query to select certain fields from a DB row but the output always contains every field in the table.

Here is my code (model):-

```
public function test() {

        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $builder = $db->table('members');
        $builder->select('mem_id');
        $builder->limit(12, 0);
        if ($builder->countAllResults() > 0) {
            $query = $builder->get();
            $result = $query->getResultArray();
            }
            else
            {
            $result = array();
            }
        return $result;
    
    }//test
```

I want the above to return just the "mem_id" value but it's returning every field in the row no matter what a put in the select statement. Does anyone know why?

In my controller, I am requesting the output as per:-

```
public function index()
    {
        $members = new Search;
        $result = $members->test();
        print_r($result); exit();
    }
```

And the result is:-

`Array ([0] => Array([mem_id] => 2 [username] => billy [email] => anemail@email.com) [1] => Array([mem_id] => 3 [username] => john [email] => anemail2@email.com) [2] => Array([mem_id] => 4 [username] => sam [email] => anemail3@email.com))`

The result should just show "mem_id" and not all the other fields. Why is the query returning everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$builder->countAllResults()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#builder-countallresults)

> Permits you to determine the number of rows in a particular Query
> Builder query.
>
> However, this method also resets any field values that you may have
> passed to `select()`. If you need to keep them, you can pass `false` as
> the first parameter.

```php
$builder->countAllResults(false);
```

Comment: You sir are a genius. I didn't know that at all as it's not made clear in the Codeignter documentation. That's solved my issue perfectly. Thanks very much for your answer.